# Reflect different data based on multiple events

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2

My problem is simple but its difficult to me. When you select option1 we have again 24h and 48h. If you click on 24h we send 24h data if you click on 48h we send 48h data. If you select option 2 same like before but we send option 2 data. (Even i don't know how to google it this type of functionality)

[image: template]

```
     Frontend:
                <ion-select [(ngModel)]="Tickcharts" interface="popover" class="selectbutton">
                    <ion-option class="option" value="value1" (ionSelect)="charts(1)">ICE G.Oil</ion-option>
                    <ion-option class="option" value="value2" (ionSelect)="charts(2)"> ICE Brent</ion-option>
                    <ion-option class="option" value="value3" (ionSelect)="charts(3)"> NYMEX H.Oil</ion-option>
                </ion-select>

              <button (ionSelect)="charts(24)"> 24H </button>
               <button (ionSelect)="charts(48)"> 48H </button>

               charts(number){
                   -- here i send number to backend service for getting specific data
               }

        Backend:

        middleware.post("/tickchartsclick", function (req, resp) {

                    var twenty_four;

                    switch (req.body.number) {
                        case 1:
                            twenty_four = "column 1 data"
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            twenty_four = "column 2 data"
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            twenty_four = "column 3 data"
                            break;
          }

          if(req.body.number == 24){
connection.query("select '"+twenty_four +"'" from charts where date = 24hours",callbackfunction)
              resp.send("send 24 hours data");
          }else{
connection.query("select '"+twenty_four +"'" from charts where date = 48hours",callbackfunction)
              resp.send("send 48 hours data");
          }
        })
```

Comment: Help me understand your question, you wish to send the data to your backend based on your options? You wish to send data to backend or receive from backend based on the options? Are you interested in knowing the way you can form data and send form backend or from the frontend?

Comment: Receive data from backend baseed on options. I am sending parameter to backend then switch statement based on req.body number there it assigns particular column which you need to query data. after that i need to send back that particular data to user. I have implemented above logic but it alwas sending 48 hour data because when i switch to particular option it goes into switch then get column field in (Mysql) then query in else loop because 24 h not evaluating when i select options.

Comment: Why dont you send the data in just one go like given below, 
{
 options1:{
  24:{},
  48:{}
 },
 options2:{
  24:{},
  48:{}
 },
 options3:{
  24:{},
  48:{}
 }
}, it will help in toggle as well?

Comment: That's also good idea but i am trying to get data when ever user click on particular element like option1 and 24h then i need to send that data only. this because i don't need to send all data even user don't want.

Comment: Hmm ok I think then you can reduce it to option like in my comment above just send option specific data not the whole. Besides make a request with option and hour and send it over. However I still feel it is not very optimised solution.

Comment: Yes i am doing exactly like that here i am sending only option which option user got clicked then `var todaydata = [];
       var yesterdaydata = [];
       resp.json({success:true,todaydata:todaydata,yesterdaydata:yesterdaydata,name:name})` after getting this response two separate charts (This data for charts) with 24h and 48h. What i try to do is i want to put two buttons with 24h and 48h if user click on 24h i have to show 24h data only and vice versa.

Comment: What i want to do is if user select option 1 then select 24h, based on these two value i need to query data from database. Now i am doing when ever user click on option then querying 24h data and 48h data both and sending to frontend.